# git - I seem to have too many remote branches. How did this happen? How do I fix it?

Tags: git

When I do this:

```
git branch -a
```

I see precisely this:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Do I have two remote branches?  How did I get in this situation?

All I have is my local directory, *MyProject*, and my remote branch on the server, *MyProject.git*.  Other projects on my PC just have *master* and *remotes/origin/master*.  Where did this *HEAD* branch come from?

Comment: Different branches are denoted by asterisks, so your only branch is `* master`. I think `remotes/origin/HEAD` points to the currently used branch, which is `origin/master/`, your only branch. But that's my interpretation...

Comment: @Blender, no, the asterisk indicates the branch you currently have checked out. "the current branch will be highlighted with an asterisk" http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html

Answer (score 4):

You only have one *local* branch and one *remote* branch.

- `master` is a reference to your local branch, and the `*` means it is the currently checked-out branch.
- `remotes/origin/HEAD` is the `HEAD` reference of the remote repository named `origin`, it is simply a pointer to the `master` branch in the `origin` remote repository.
- `remotes/origin/master` is the reference to the `master` branch on the remote repository named `origin`.

The last two exist so that Git can keep track of where the remote repository is (or was at the last `git fetch`).

Comment: Then why don't my other projects look like this?  The others don't have that HEAD line.

Comment: @Kyralessa: Git is a little funky about its remote HEAD detection. Not all operations fetch it, and it's only fetched by SHA1, not as a symref, so Git has to infer from that hash what branch it's probably pointing to. I believe the exact behavior has changed through various versions, too - so if you cloned one repo with one version, and another with another, you might've fetched `HEAD` in one but not the other? You can try `git remote show origin` - it should show something like "HEAD branch: master", and might refresh things.

Comment: Kyraless, your other repositories may be bare.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540883/whats-the-practical-difference-between-a-bare-and-non-bare-repository/5541917#5541917.

Comment: @Derek that answer has nothing to do with the state of the remote branch.

Comment: Andrew, Kyralessa said that her other projects "don't have that HEAD line" which I guessed means they don't have the remote origin.  This may be because they don't have any remote repositories or may be bare.