# Local directories as git repository and working copy

Tags: git, version-control

WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE---

I know little about git and trying to learn it. I don't have git installed in my server.

Hence I am trying to create a folder(**Git Repos Folder**) in my system that will act as a directory of repositories. (Like repositories created in GitHub) and another folder(**Git Clones Folder**) where I can clone the repos and work on them.( Like local clones of github repositories).

I want to be able to commit and push from any of the repositories in **Git Clones Folder** to the respective repositories in **Git Repos Folder**.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED -

I created a repo named **praveenpuglia.com** inside **Git Repos Folder** and ran `git init` to make it a git repository.

Next I cloned the repo as **praveenpuglia.com** inside **Git Clones Folder** using `git clone D:/Git Repos Folder/praveenpuglia.com`

I put a *readme* file , staged and committed it.

When I try to push the changes to the master, I get these errors

```
Pushing to D:/Git Repos Folder/praveenpuglia.com
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master[K
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository[K
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent[K
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match[K
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.[K
remote: error: [K
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to[K
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into[K
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you[K
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some[K
remote: error: other way.[K
remote: error: [K
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set[K
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.[K
To D:/Git Repos Folder/praveenpuglia.com
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to D:/Git Repos Folder/praveenpuglia.com'
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I set it up? I have tried few of the available answers here but could not understand.

Comment: Read this book, it will help :) http://git-scm.com/book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to push to the remote repository it must be created as bare repository.
You can convert remote repository to bare by:

```
git config --bool core.bare true
```

Comment: I did that and pushed from the clone. It got pushed. however the pushed file is not reflected in the **D:/Git Repos Folder/praveenpuglia.com** folder.

Comment: Try to check 'git log' on your remote repository.  Do you see all your commits ?

Comment: log shows the commit although it does not show the readme file. 

    Author: Praveen Puglia <praveenpuglia@gmail.com>
    Date:   Sun Feb 23 20:38:48 2014 +0530
    Initial Commit. Readme added.

Comment: It is correct behaviour for the bare repository. You can try to clone another copy of your remote repository and check that your readme file present on clone repository.

Comment: Great. So the new one has the readme but I am still confused as to what's the role of a bare repo then? Would love some education on it.

Comment: May be it helps you to get the difference between the bare and non-bare repositories https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540883/whats-the-practical-difference-between-a-bare-and-non-bare-repository

Comment: I am starting to wonder how it works for github when you create a repo there, clone it locally, commit and push the changes. The files are also reflected in the github repo too right? How does this happen when that git repo has a working tree?

Comment: I cannot answer to this question because I am not working in the GitHub :)  But you can install GitLab (it is very similar to github) locally and check it.

Comment: `it must be created as bare repository` - that's not true, as should be obvious from the error message. It _should_ be a bare repo, but that's not "must".