# Source code with project-name.git how do I checkout

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have this zip file. I have no idea how to checkout the source.

Here is the folder.
[image: git folder structure]

As my understanding. Normally the git folder is .git. I am not sure how come it is like this.

I tried to rename the shiroproject.git to .git, and try to run `git status`
then it prompted **This operation must be run in a work tree**

Can anyone help on this matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like he may have sent you a zip of the [bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540883/whats-the-practical-difference-between-a-bare-and-non-bare-repository). If so you will need to clone it to have normal `git` access to the files within. Try the following from the folder where `shiroproject.git` is located...

```
$ git clone ./shiroproject.git shiroproject
$ cd shiroproject
$ git status
```

Comment: the folder have about 45mb, after git clone, it only have 1 README.md. and I run `git log`, it only have 1 commit message which is **Initial Commit**... Anything I missed out?

Comment: OK, I use GUI git program to open the folder, I manage to view the repo more detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try and treat the `X.git` directory as a remote, and do a git clone of it, that will extract the working tree and you should see the project.