# Git Files not being pushed to remote repository [Windows]

Tags: windows, git, shell, git-remote

So I'm just learning Git, and can't tell what I'm doing wrong in setting up a local and remote repo for my scripts. Originally, the remote repo was going to live on a fileshare (\server\share$\scripts), but I can't even seem to get this to work on my local machine.

I've done my research, and read up on some of the common pitfalls, but I still can't seem to get files accurately reflected in my remote repo when pushing from the local one.

What I have:

Local Repo: In C:\git, with one file "test.txt" created by:

```
cd C:\git
git init
echo "Hello World" > test.txt
git add .
git commit
```

Remote Repo: C:\test

```
git --bare init
```

Then, when I specify a remove branch with:

```
git remote add origin C:\test
git push origin master
```

It tells me all is fine:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 315 bytes | 315.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To C:\test
   06e076a..62b6130  master -> master
```

And further `git pushes` return "Everything up-to-date", but the files are never pushed to the remote repository. Querying the logfile indicates that the push did in fact take place:

```
commit 62b6130cedef529ef97aec5333fcbee96c5e9a2f (HEAD -> master)
Author: [Redacted]
Date:   Wed Jan 24 15:21:37 2018 -0500
TEST COMMIT
```

So where are the files? I'm on the right branch (master), and I even ran a `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch false` because some other similar threads suggested this as a fix.

Looking for some guidance here, appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your remote repository is a bare repository. This means there simply is no checked out working tree. Just the git objects and branches and tags.

Having a working tree (aka your files in the most up to date master branch) doesn't make any sense for a remote repository. This is where you store **all** versions of **all** your files in one place. How should git know which branch/version/commit to use in the working tree?

I also found this description: [Source](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/)

- `git init` is for working
- `git init --bare` is for sharing

To get your files back again, you need to clone from there.

```
git clone C:\test .
```

This will create a new repository with working tree.

Here are some links:

- [What's the -practical- difference between a Bare and non-Bare repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540883/whats-the-practical-difference-between-a-bare-and-non-bare-repository)
- http://bare-vs-nonbare.gitrecipes.de/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, especially regarding "working tree". The goal was to have a working + staging directory where I could test and then commit changes (preserving file history), then push the production version to the folder they'll actually need to be called from. 

I started in web development, so that's the kind of flow I was looking for. How should I have accomplished this in git? Or is this not how git works, and am I simply approaching this wrong?

Comment: I know that pushing to non-bare repos is not advised, so is what I'm trying to do just fundamentally incorrect?