# What does happen if I stage a file, then modify it and do a commit and push?

Tags: git, github, commit, git-stage

So, for example, if I have a file *index.html* and change some lines and execute `git add index.html`. Then I will again modify *index.html* but will not stage change. And do `git commit` and `git push`. Will my last changes applied in `commit`/`push`?

Comment: have you tried this first ? please tell your finding first

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The last changes added to the staging area will be in the commit. This is also known as cached. Use `git diff --cached` to see what will be committed or commit and `git show HEAD` to see what was committed. Get into the know with [Recording Changes to the Repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository), the section _Viewing Your Staged and Unstaged Changes_ might be particularly interesting for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49228610/341994

Answer (score 4):

No, your *last changes* will not be commit and push to git server. Only the files where are in *staging area* (`git add`) would be *committed* and can be *pushed*. If you change a file and do not add to the staging area (`git add`), then you don‘t commit or push it to  the git server.

If you want to add the last changes also and push it to the server, just `git add` again and then *commit* and *push* it.

Answer (score 0):

"git commit" works on files that are in staging area. So, your first change to *index.html* which you staged will be part of your commit and push. Remember the name is **Staging Area**, a separate place where you want to accumulate all your changes that you want to commit.

Now, lets try to understand what happens when you do your second change to *index.html*
If you do "git status", you will see that now *index.html* is listed both in staging area and also in modified files. And if you do "git diff" on *index.html*, only your second change will be shown as diff. And, if you want to include this change also into your commit, you just to "git add" on this file again. So, what happens to the already staged file. It will be updated with a file which has both changes.