# Pushing to a shared network drive?

Tags: git, git-bare

I want to develop first on my local machine, and then push it to the shared drive /R. I think I might not be using terminology correctly, so feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. Basically, if I have a directory tree and files set up such as "Template", "/Downloads", I want the network drive to exactly replicate "Template", "/Downloads".

I initialize my own project and then set up a bare repository in /R and after every commit to my own project, push to it to the origin. However, when I click over to the /R directory, it just looks like the inside of a .git folder instead of my actual project.

What is the sequence of steps I need to follow to be able to develop on my machine and push how the whole folder looks to the drive?

Comment: That’s what a bare repo is. Are you wanting to deploy using git?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540883/whats-the-practical-difference-between-a-bare-and-non-bare-repository

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `push`, but `pull` from the shared drive (non-bare) should achieve what you're after.

If you need to run it from you local repo for convenience you can create a script that

1. captures your `pwd`
2. `cd` to your shared drive
3. `git pull` from your local
4. `cd`back to where you were from step 1