# Get working files (source code artifacts) from GitLab backup

Tags: gitlab

I'm given a Gitlab backup (using command `gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create` from my team that doesn't have any source code file. The system team only gave me data disk that I could attach to a virtual machine. After attaching data disk I can only see .git structure which looks very much like bare repository explained here [What's the -practical- difference between a Bare and non-Bare repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540883/whats-the-practical-difference-between-a-bare-and-non-bare-repository)

Is there a way that I can get source code file from that backup?

Answer (score 0):

Note: a GitLab backup would include bare repositories anyway.

But to get source files from a bare repository, simply clone it anywhere you want.

```
git clone /path/to/bare/repo.git
```

Comment: I did and it returned to me **You appear to have cloned an empty repository**. May I really miss something? Note that I have that backup and I attached the backup into a virtual machine (without any GitLab installed). I have Git client installed though.

Comment: That .git, is it the content of your attached disk, representing the backup, or is it the result of a gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore command (to restore GitLab)?

Comment: I took a backup, attached to my virtual machine and I could see list of all repos. Every repo has the same structure (HEAD, hooks, refs..). I did git clone ... and it cloned an empty repository and return me the message.

Comment: Then the GitLab backup included an empty repository in its backup. Are they *all* empty?

Comment: I'm not sure because as far as I can see, every .git dir has the same size and same structure. I did randomly clone 8-10 repos (in a backup there is around 1000 repos) but all gave me the same response that the cloned ones are empty.

Comment: @EagleDev And you did a restore (`gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore`)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202616/discussion-between-eagledev-and-vonc).