# How to see your own file in Gogs locally?

Tags: git, gogs

I'm configuring a Gogs on my windows and upload my file on localhost:3000. 
I Know, my information saves in the SQL database with Xampp.

but how can I see uploaded files in My PC, not on Web?

Update:
I see these files in the picture but can not see my source files that uploaded on the web!
[see files that create with Gogs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH1to.png)

Comment: Check what gogs uses as its `ROOT`, that should be where the raw repositories are stored.

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks to replying, I updated the question.

Comment: What you are seeing is a [bare git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540883/whats-the-practical-difference-between-a-bare-and-non-bare-repository). There's no point in having in active checkout in there, because Gogs just serves the actual "git" parts and not the files itself directly.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, thanks for the quick reply.