# Should I use git-filter-repo on the repo clone or on the self hosted bare repo?

Tags: git, blob, bfg-repo-cleaner, git-filter-repo

There's a self hosted git repository on a Windows Server (Bonobo based if anyone interested). The repository got bloated up because of binary blobs and I'd like to strip out these large blobs along with their whole history.

I was looked at `bfg` / `git filter-branch`, `bfg-ish`, and `git filter-repo`. My question I think is invariant of these however it sounds like `git filter-repo` is the most advised.

The big question: should I execute the `--strip-blobs-bigger-than 4M` on the repository clone (working copy), or should I go straight ahead and manipulate the hosted bare repo what the Bobono manages? If I execute it on the client clone than how will the changes propagate into Bonobo? These changes will be pretty fundamental, will they be even committable?

I already backed up everything, did some filter-repo analysis. I included the blobs in gitignore (although their modification still show as a change).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up operating on the hosted bare repository. It looks like filter-repo is intended to be used on a clean clone of a repository:

```
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 4M
Aborting: Refusing to destructively overwrite repo history since
this does not look like a fresh clone.
  (expected freshly packed repo)
Please operate on a fresh clone instead.  If you want to proceed
anyway, use --force.
```

So I retried on a clean clone and the instruction ran, but then I was clueless what to do next. There were no file changes per se to commit or push, the "meta data" was modified. The operation also interestingly stripped `[remote "origin"]` and `[branch "master"]` from the `.git/config` so I needed to re-establish remote and branch.

So I decided to just go ahead and modify the hosted bare repo. The tool recognizes that it is not a clean clone:

```
warning: no corresponding .pack: ./objects/pack/pack-f8fc2556f0b95c1a66219fe3ad3fe41d6319a985.idx
Aborting: Refusing to destructively overwrite repo history since
this does not look like a fresh clone.
  (expected freshly packed repo)
Please operate on a fresh clone instead.  If you want to proceed
anyway, use --force.
```

With forcing the meta data size decreased from 1.3GB to 150MB, similarly as it was executed on the clean clone meta data.

```
> git filter-repo --force --strip-blobs-bigger-than 4M
Processed 19965 blob sizes
Parsed 3536 commits
New history written in 1.44 seconds; now repacking/cleaning...
Repacking your repo and cleaning out old unneeded objects
Enumerating objects: 42458, done.
Counting objects: 100% (42458/42458), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (12993/12993), done.
Writing objects: 100% (42458/42458), done.
Selecting bitmap commits: 3257, done.
Building bitmaps: 100% (137/137), done.
Total 42458 (delta 33284), reused 37896 (delta 29067), pack-reused 0
Removing duplicate objects: 100% (256/256), done.
Completely finished after 10.20 seconds.
```

This happens to be a Windows environment, I started off of a clean clone after that, and I had to re-trust the repository in Visual Studio and all that. So far I could push some changes and I'll report back if anything seems to not work.

It's another story if you are dealing with a repository managed by GitHub or other git services, in this case you won't have direct access to the bare repository they manage. Not sure what happens in that case. I guess you can push the meta data change somehow? Someone should comment.

Comment: What is a "genesis repo"?

Comment: @matt not sure what's the proper name but that's the hosted repo, the "O.G." repo. That's what the git server governs and everyone clones. That's where everyone commits. I know got is all decentralized, but git server is a central point in practice.

Comment: So you didn't "treat the genesis repo" (meaningless phrase anyway). You operated on a fresh clone, which is what the docs advise: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#FRESHCLONE

Comment: @matt I didn't operate on a clone. I operated on the hosted original repository. You cannot do that with GitHub or GitLab or BitBucket, but since I'm self hosting I could. How can I describe this better? That's the repo which first existed, originally created. All other clients cloned that. But this is not a clone of anything, it is itself.

Comment: @matt So imagine you create an empty repo via GitHub UI. Then you can clone that, but that repository at GitHub was the first one, it is not a clone of anything. In my case since I self host, I have access to that and I went ahead and operated on it directly.

Comment: @CsabaToth There is no "genesis repo" in git. The repo on the server is usually a bare repo that doesn't have a working tree.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540883/whats-the-practical-difference-between-a-bare-and-non-bare-repository

Comment: @mx0 correct, I modified both my question and answer with that, thanks!